# Why does my Arraylist keep printing [3,2]?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to remove every instance of value from an array of integers, and return the length of the new array of integers.The input is [3,2,2,3], with val being 3. The output should be [2,2], with length 2. I keep getting [3,2], but I am removing val through an array.

```
    class Solution {
        public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {

            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            list.add(nums[i]);
            }

            if(list.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if(list.get(i) == val) {
                list.remove(i);
                }
            }
            return list.size();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Try running it under a debugger?

Comment: I tried your function and it does output [2,2], I did the printing before the return statement. Maybe you actually want to return the array and not the size ?

Comment: right, I think as answered by Sami Kuhmonen. We need to see the code for printing the elements.

Comment: Works fine. Can be done a lot nicer with stream api though: `return Arrays.stream(nums).filter(num -> num != val).count()`

Comment: Note that the correct way to mutate the existing list is to use an iterator and `it.remove()`.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove the first 3 you will have i=0 and next the array list will resize, so when you delete you need to do i - -.

```
class Solution {
        public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {

            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            list.add(nums[i]);
            }

            if(list.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if(list.get(i) == val) {
                list.remove(i);
                i--;
                }
            }
            return list.size();
        }
   }
```

Comment: That makes sense. Even though it resizes, why do you decrement it? Because I thought when you remove, new sized array would look like [2,2,3]?

Comment: One way to solve you problem is decrement, because when you remove one object from the array list your next object will get that position and you are going increment i and skip that object. For example:

Comment: If your array list size is equal to 4 and your var i = 2, you will delete the position 2 and your object on third will come be at 2 and your var i = 3, and you don’t check that one

Comment: So when you decrement your var I will be 2 again and you will can check

Comment: Did you want to return the list? You are returning the size

Comment: The question requires me to return the size. This is the question:

Comment: Given an array nums and a value val, remove all instances of that value in-place and return the new length.
Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the new length.

Comment: What are you printing?

Comment: The list is actually printing. But the return type is an integer.

Comment: Sry, where are you printing? And it’s the array value equal to [3,2] are you sure?

Comment: I’m printing in an online compiler on Leetcode, and I’m positive it’s [3,2]

Comment: On my Compiller it's working. See The answer of SmartManoj

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t shown any printing code but I assume you print `nums` based on the number returned by this method. That means you never change `nums` in any way and just print the first n numbers from there. You need to return the modified array instead of just the length.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call remove at all (while removing like you do, it is okay, but for example, if you do this in a foreach cycle, it would crash on `ConcurrentModificationException`. Instead, you can determine whether to add item to the resulting list or not inside the first `for` loop (which is in my opinion safer):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] != val) {
        list.add(nums[i]);
    }
}
return list.size();
```

(I know that this does not answer your question directly)

Comment: This print an output of nothing.